React-bootstrap how to add custom class/style to .dropdown-menu in NavDropdown
Is there a more direct method besides importing custom css? The current situation is very inconvenient. thanks
<NavDropdown title='nav dropdown' id='basic-nav-dropdown' align='end'>
  <NavDropdown.Item href='#'>1</NavDropdown.Item>
  <NavDropdown.Item href='#'>2</NavDropdown.Item>
  <NavDropdown.Item href='#'>3</NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>;


Please use the <Dropdown.Menu> Tag and the menu to follow the steps below:
<NavDropdown
      title='nav dropdown'
      id='basic-nav-dropdown'
      align='end'
      menu={({ children, ...props }) => (
        <Dropdown.Menu
          {...props}
          className="your-custom-class"
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightblue' }}
        >
          {children}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      )}
    >
      <NavDropdown.Item href='#'>1</NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href='#'>2</NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href='#'>3</NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>


I got a warning: "Warning: Invalid value for prop menu on  tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM", and the className and style didnt show.

Alright, post your code with me in the codesandbox so I can resolve this.
